# Customizing the content of what's posted to the user's friends' feeds when they "like" my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When a user likes my site, a feed item gets published to the user who liked my site friends' feeds. I'm using XFBML and referencing [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

I would like to, along with the url that gets published, insert a picture and title and subtitle - as I've seen accompanied by other "like posts". Here's my code:

I have some meta tags in the head of the page (note that this page requires that the user is signed in so it's not accessable to any crawlers - I'm not sure if this matters)

```
  %meta{:property => "og:title", :content => "#{@product.brand.heading}'s #{@product.title}"}
  %meta{:property => "og:type", :content => "company"}
  %meta{:property => "og:url", :content => brand_product_url(@brand, @product)}

  %meta{:property => "og:image", :content => @product.picture1.url(:small)}
  %meta{:property => "og:site_name", :content => "some name"}
  %meta{:property => "fb:app_id", :content => "my app id"}
```

And then I have what's required by XFMBL:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'my is', appSecret: 'my secrete', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});

    //hide the text of the like button after it loads
    $('.connect_widget_button_count_count').hide();

  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

And then I have the like button itself:

```
 <fb:like show_faces="false" layout="button_count" width="155"></fb:like>
```

I would like what's in the meta tags listed above to be in what gets posted by users who like this page. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have some meta tags in the head of
>   the page (note that this page requires
>   that the user is signed in so it's not
>   accessable to any crawlers - I'm not
>   sure if this matters)

Yes this does matter, the page containing the meta tags needs to be accessible to facebook. Try http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/ to test.